# How can I tell the location where an application is writing to the hard drive on Mac OSX?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, osx-el-capitan

I installed a new customer manager for our client and it creates cache files when downloading reports on our server. But it doesn't seem to be removing them. I've had this with two programs so far and the client is telling us its our software.

Is there a tool built in method in OSX that tells us where the application is writing their files to?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know at least a partial name for these files, or some part of the content...

Spotlight won't search hidden or system locations for such as these, so the simplest way if you don't want to get into terminal & grep is to get an app that does.

The simplest is [EasyFind](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/easyfind/id411673888?mt=12) - freeware - & though slower than Spotlight because it doesn't use indexing, will happily trawl entire drives for matches, search inside file contents/packages if required.

No affiliation, just a satisfied user.